Google Chrome's inspector is crashing, lagging, self-closing etc. (?)
From about two weeks time, my inspector is playing really bad tricks on me.
It's lagging, crashing mostly on device emulation mode, really slow etc.
I was wondering if it's just me or is anyone else experiencing this, because I can't relate it to something that I've done or changed on my system. Nor settings, nor installations. It just started happening every day now. And I can't find a ticket about it either.
Chrome Version 126.0.6478.183 (Official Build) (arm64)
Mac mini M1, 2020, Sonoma 14.5
I tried reseting, restarting, clearing caches, but nothing changed much. The issue is mostly when I use the device emulation mode.
